# styling react-select using classes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select, classname

I am using react-select in my code. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

I want to style my drop down using classNames, so that I referred https://react-select.com/styles. The DOM structure of react slect is shown in the link.

How can I style the react-select using classNames?

Can anyone show a sample code?

Answer (score 17):

According to the [documentation](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames)

> If you provide the className prop to react-select, the SelectContainer
>   will be given a className based on the provided value.

So it should work like this:

```
<Select className="abc" .... />
```

Then you can use your classname as usual.

```
.abc {
color: red;
}
```

## You can also use classNamePrefix

by specifing a classNamePrefix, react-select will render all classNames with your prefix. If you use this:

```
<Select className="abc" classNamePrefix="react-select" ... />
```

Your Select will automatically render a class structure like this:
[image]

Comment: How could you use the classNamePrefix with CSS Modules?

Answer (score 8):

See their example:

```
For example, given className='react-select-container' and classNamePrefix="react-select", the DOM structure is similar to this:

<div class="react-select-container">
  <div class="react-select__control">
    <div class="react-select__value-container">...</div>
    <div class="react-select__indicators">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="react-select__menu">
    <div class="react-select__menu-list">
      <div class="react-select__option">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in your css, simply do:

```
.react-select-container {
  background-color: 'red';
}

.react-select__menu {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

etc

Comment: Why you have used height:100vh in .react-select__menu?

Comment: If I do my CSS as you said does it automatically the react-select or shall I specify the className in the `<Select>` tag? @Max

Comment: yes, give like the example says, give it: className='react-select-container' and classNamePrefix="react-select"

Answer (score 2):

As per the [react-select](https://react-select.com/) official docs, there is a two ways to edit the styles by class names.

**1. Static, by setting the [classNamePrefix](https://react-select.com/styles#the-classnameprefix-prop) and overriding the componen class names in your own less or css file:**

Styles in your less file:

```
.react-select-container {
  .react-select__menu-list {
    background-color: #4ca6f1;
  }
}
```

React component:

```
<Select
  {...props}
  className="react-select-container"
  classNamePrefix="react-select"
/>
```

HTML output:

```
<div class="react-select-container">
  <div class="react-select__control">
    <div class="react-select__value-container">...</div>
    <div class="react-select__indicators">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="react-select__menu">
    <div class="react-select__menu-list">
      <div class="react-select__option">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Dynamically, by setting classnames using prop [classNames](https://react-select.com/styles#the-classnames-prop):**

React component:

```
<Select
  classNames={{
    control: (state) => state.isFocused ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-grey-300',
  }}
/>
```